# Creating a unique meta description for each page on a WordPress website

Tags: seo, google, post

I have one website which is created with WordPress. When I try to enter the websites's homepage meta description, then it attaches to all the posts that are created by me on the website.

But I want different meta tags for every different pages on my website including homepage. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how your theme is set up and what options it provides but the simplest solution would be to use a plugin such as [Wordpress SEO by Yoast](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/) which provides the ability to create page titles and meta tags individually for all pages/posts as well as the homepage.